# Sesquilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, sesquilinear-forms

Let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension on $\mathbb C$, $B$ a basis of $V$ , and $f, g$ two sesquilinear forms. If $B$ is an orthonormal basis for $f$ and for $g$ then $f=g$.

I want to know if the following statement is true or false. It does not seem false to me because I feel like any vector can be written as a linear combination of elements in $B$ and the images of the basis are equal. But I also feel like the fact we are in $\mathbb C$ gives a counter example I am not thinking of. What do you think ?

Comment: "But I also feel like the fact we are in C gives a counter example I am not thinking of." --- OK, can you try to write a down a proof for real vector spaces?

Comment: @JacobManaker for $x, y \in V$, $f(x,y) = x^T A_B y = x^T I_n y = g(x,y)$

Comment: I don't follow.  Why is $g(x,y)=x^{\mathsf{T}}y$?  Why is $A_B=I_n$?

Comment: @JacobManaker because $B$ is orthonormal

Comment: Do you mean the transpose is to be taken with respect to coordinates in $B$, and not the standard basis?

Comment: ...and you still haven't explained why $A_B=I_n$.